# Google Maps Geocoding i18n

Tags: google-maps, internationalization

I'm using Google Maps Geocoding via json in my i18n website to validate event addresses and save them to ddbb.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding

My main problem is that if an user (with english lang in browser) register an event address in Spain, I will get country as Spain instead of España (and the same problem for adminAreas, city, etc).

For countries we have countryCode that solves the problem, but there isn't a code for cities.  **This results in duplicated (not related) cities in my ddbb.**

**Is there a way to get results in several languages in the same json request to be able to save translations?**

There is the language parameter, but i don't think we can't put several codes separated by coma (because is not explained in documentation).

The only solution I've is make different requests for every lang in my site before save a new address.

Answer (score 0):

We have now an **optional parameter 'language'** to tell google geocode api wich one to use:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/index#ReverseGeocoding
https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#languagesupport

Here you can find language codes supported:
https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=p9pdwsai2hDMsLkXsoM05KQ&gid=1

```
geocoder.geocode( { 'address': addresInputField.value, 'language': 'es'}, function(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
    //do whatever with results
    return true;
  } else {
    //do whatever with errors
    return false;
  }
});
```